# How use Qt.QNetworkAccessManager() for an array of pictures

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I get a list of pictures from the Internet (links), I need to display them without downloading to the device
How use Qt.QNetworkAccessManager() for an array of pictures?

```
    def createCellWidget(self, pix, btn):
        layout = QGridLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.picture = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap(pix)
        self.b(pix)

        self.picture.setFixedSize(250, 370)
        layout.addWidget(self.picture, 0, 0)
        self.lbl_checkbox = QCheckBox(self.picture)
        self.lbl_checkbox.setText(btn)
        return frame

    def b(self, h):
        self.nam = Qt.QNetworkAccessManager()
        print("Load image")
        url = h
        self.nam.get(Qt.QNetworkRequest(Qt.QUrl(url)))
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.finish_request)

    def finish_request(self, reply):
        img = Qt.QPixmap()

        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())

        self.picture.setPixmap(img)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what problem you're facing and provide a valid [mre]. Also, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details): "One QNetworkAccessManager instance should be enough for the whole Qt application."